# Allow review queue to be clickable after limit reached

Tags: feature-request, review

I think it would be a good feature to allow the review queue link in the review section to be clickable, even when you have reached your limit for the day.

For example in this screenshot:

> [image]

The linking is disabled. But I can still manually go to https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits to see my stats and history. However, this requires someone with knowledge of the url scheme's to be able to do this.

By always making it clickable and just displaying the limit reached message in that review queues page, people can still see their stats and history for that review queue.

Comment: You can get there by clicking the "recent reviews" link which is always enabled.